# Angular 2 POST don't send data to ASP.NET server

Tags: asp.net, angular

I would like to send data from client to ASP.NET MVC server using POST method. Web api action was called, but data haven't been sent to server. When I open Fiddler, i see data.
Here is my code:

**Client**

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http.post('http://localhost/app/api/Users/', 'hello', { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
  .subscribe(user => {
    console.log(user);
  });
```

**Server**

```
   [HttpPost]
   public void Post([FromBody]string data)
   {
      //data is null
   }
```

Where is the problem? Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

The value is not form encoded but that is what you specify in your `content-type` header. Change the value to this:

```
'=hello'
```

Full call

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/app/api/Users/', '=hello', { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
  .subscribe(user => {
    console.log(user);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, you have to use formdata:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('data': 'hello');
```

Comment: Ok, but when I use `application/json`, I get response 401 Unauthorized. Why? I use Windows authentication. And GET is ok, when i add `withCredentials:true`

Comment: Why do you use the FromBody by the way? Why not just: [HttpPost("{data}")] public void Post(string data)

Comment: When I use FormData my response is 401 Unauthorized

Comment: How are you authenticated at your server? do you need to add an Authentication header?

Comment: I use Windows authentication. In client app i must add to all http requests this: `{withCredentials: true}` and in server I have this http headers: `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />`. I dont need to add Authentication header.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET won't deserialize the body if you don't specify the correct content-type and give clue about the match between the received body and the name of variables.

One possibility is to serialize the body to JSON, with matching variable names, like that :

```
    let model = { data: "Hello" }
    let req = new Headers();
    req.headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');

    let body = JSON.stringify(model);

    this.http.post(url, body, req).subscribe(...)
```